# Java ArrayList of ? extends Interface

Tags: java, generics, collections, interface, arraylist

I have a group of classes that all implement a validation interface which has the method `isValid()`. I want to put a group of objects--all of different classes--into an ArrayList, loop through them and call `isValid()` on each.

Here's my code

```
Email email = new email();
Address address = new Address();

ArrayList<? extends Validation> myValidationObjects = new ArrayList();
```

But when I try to do:

```
myValidationObjects.add(email);
```

I get:

> The method add(capture#2-of ? extends Validation) in the type ArrayList 
>    is not applicable for the arguments (Email)

Both `Email` and `Address` implement Validation.

According to [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html), I should be able to use `extends` for both interfaces and subclasses.

Comment: Why not to use `ArrayList<Validation>` without any `extends`?

Comment: `? extends Validation` means some _specific but unknown_ subclass of `Validation`.  For all the compiler knows, it could be some other subclass completely unrelated to `Email` or `Address`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
List<Validation> myValidationObjects = new ArrayList<>();           // Java 7
List<Validation> myValidationObjects = new ArrayList<Validation>(); // pre Java 7
```

Now you can add any instance of a class that implements `Validation` to that list.

Answer (score 7):

`List<? extends Validation> myValidationObjects`

#### Incorrect reading

"`myValidationObjects` is list of objects that extend `Validation`."

#### Correct reading

"`myValidationObjects` can be a list of any type that extends `Validation`. For example, it could be a `List<RangeValidation>` or a `List<RegexValidation>`."

Since there is no object you can legitimately add to both a `List<RangeValidation>` and a `List<RegexValidation>`, Java prevents you to call `add` on a variable of such type.

Your case is in fact the simpler one: you need the definite type `List<Validation>`.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration `ArrayList<? extends Validation>` means a list of an unknown class that extends `Validation`. `Email` is not compatible with this unknown class.

You can use `ArrayList<Validation>` for your list.

Answer (score 2):

If a generic class's `T` is `<? extends Foo>`, then the only thing you can pass to a method that takes `T` is `null` -- *not* any subclass that extends `Foo`.

The reason is that `List<? extends Validation>` doesn't mean "a list of things that extend Validation". You can get that with just `List<Validation>`. Instead, it means "a list of some type, such that that type extends Validation."

It's a subtle distinction, but basically the idea is that `List<? extends T>` is a subtype of `List<T>`, and you therefore *don't* want to be able to insert anything into it. Think of this case:

```
List<FooValidation> foos = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends Validation> validations = foos; // this is allowed
validations.add(new BarValidation()); // not allowed! this is your question
FooValidation foo = foos.get(0);
```

If the third line were allowed, then the last line would throw a ClassCastException.