# Adding data to generic ? extends list

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java ArrayList of ? extends Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164501/java-arraylist-of-extends-interface)

There is this code:

```
public static class B1 {}
public static class B2 extends B1 {}
public void fun() {
    List<? extends B1> l3 = new ArrayList<>();
    l3.add(new B2());
}
```

Compile error:

```
java: no suitable method found for add(Main.B2)
    method java.util.List.add(int,capture#1 of ? extends Main.B1) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.util.List.add(capture#1 of ? extends Main.B1) is not applicable
      (actual argument Main.B2 cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends Main.B1 by method invocation conversion)
```

I guess that `? extends B1` means *any type that extends from B1*. It seems that type B2 extends from B1, so why object of this type cannot be added to the list and how to make it so that it can be added?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I guess that `? extends B1` means *any type that extends from B1*.

No.  It means "a specific, but unknown, type that extends from B1".  As the specific type is unknown, the compiler cannot enforce it, therefore operations like `add` don't work.<sup>*</sup>

See the [tutorial on wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

> how to make it so that it can be added?

Basically, don't use wildcards for this.  You probably want this:

```
List<B1> l3 = new ArrayList<B1>();
```

---

<sub>* Well, they do work, but only for `null` (and a few other cases, see @Marko's comment below).</sub>

Comment: * they also work for `list.add(list.get(0))` and similar combinations, due to wildcard capture.

Comment: @Oli You are correct. Its great answer but for assignment where specific type is known, it works.So i find little bit of discrepency in wild card:).See my answer

Answer (score 2):

`? extends B1` means: *some type being or extending B1, but we don't know which one*. So the list could be a `List<B1>`, or a `List<B2>`, or a `List<B3>` (assuming B3 also extends B1). And you don't want to add a B2 to a `List<B3>`, so the compiler forbids it.

You probably want a `List<B1>`.

Answer (score 1):

So you want a list of elements of type `B1` I guess. Every *child* of `B1` can be saved in a list of `B1` like this:

```
public static class B1 {}
public static class B2 extends B1 {}
public void fun() {
    List<B1> l3 = new ArrayList<>();
    l3.add(new B2());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make B1 and B2 to implement the same interface say B (can even be empty) and then declare the list <B> instead. You will be able to add and remove members without issues.

The major problem with direct inheritance can be summarized as:

```
class B1 {};
class B2 extends B1{};

ArrayList<B2> list;

addMembers(list); // Error here

void addMembers(ArrayList<B1> list) {
  list.add(new B1());
}
```

Here we declare a list of B2's and pass it as a parameter to the method that would expect list of B1's. As each B2 is also B1, it is kind of intuitive this should work. But now, in this method, it becomes legal to add also B1 to the passed list. The collection would be broken when the method returns, containing the member B1 that is not allowed by declaration.

To prevent this, the compiler will not allow to call `addMembers` with the collection of "compatible inherited type". I found this to be quite a nasty limitation that can be easily worked around by using interfaces as proposed. It is rather complex to get this right also with wildcards. You think you can just write `? extends B1`?

```
void test() {
    ArrayList<? extends B1> list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(new B1()); // Error here
    list.add(new B2()); // Error here
    test2(list);
}

void test2(ArrayList<? extends B1> list) {
    list.add(new B1()); // Error here, the collection is read only.
}
```

This is I say, these wildcards are not worth the pain involved. And you can also write `ArrayList<? extends java.lang.Object>`  or even `ArrayList< ? >` , will not be helpful, such declarations still make the collection read only.

Hence, I would say, better

```
interface B {};
class B1 implements B {};
class B2 extends B1 implements B {};  

ArrayList<B> list = new ArrayList<B>();
list.add(new B1());
list.add(new B2());
test2(list);

void test2(ArrayList<B> list) {
    list.add(new B1());
}
```

Comment: `B2` already extends `B1`...

Comment: This does not matter much. You can only add B1 to List<B1> you can only add B2 to List<B2> (also when B2 is derived from B1), but you can always add B to List<B> even if B is an interface and you can also use B to access shared features and you can also have multiple inferfaces if the objects join several collections of very different kind. I really do not recommend to mess with various <.. extends .. > if you need different classes in the collection, the amount of pain involved does not pay back.

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas: as B2 already extends B1, a List<B1> can accept instances of B1 and instances of B2, since an instance of B2 *is a* B1. No need for a B interface. You're wrong. Test it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As this question has been already answered but i would also like to add something valuable here.As everybody suggested of doing

```
List<B1> l3 = new ArrayList<B1>();
```

Thats correct. But to understand the logic you should also try below which does not give any error.

```
public void fun() {
    List<? extends B1> l3 = new ArrayList<>();
    List list1= new ArrayList();
    list1.add(Element1 extending B1);
    list1.add(Element2 extending B1);
    l3=list1;
}

 or you can also try
public void fun() {
        List<? extends B1> l3 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<B1> list1= new ArrayList();
        list1.add(B1 element);
        l3=list1;
    }
```

So your below statement is kind of true but for assignment not for add method. In nutshell for add operation it has to be really unknown type (like null) but

> ? extends B1 means any type that extends from B1.

Comment: That first example should give a compile-time warning, and isn't type-safe.  It's definitely not recommended.

Comment: I agree that it's not recommended but my intention here is just to make concept clear